# Django DigitalOcean Apps Deployment

Tags: django, digital-ocean-apps

I have a very small application that I am working on.  I have everything up and running locally but can't get it deployed to DigitalOcean Apps.  I have re-read all the tutorials and just can't get past this one spot.  See the error below

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqWQL.png)

So I have manually created the static file directories in the project, I ran the python manage.py collectstatic --noinput command locally and it did its job and put the files in the STATIC_ROOT directory.  I also changed things out and the module name will change based on the order of the requirements.txt

I really have no idea what I can do to fix this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  It feels like it is a really simple fix but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Did you run `pip install dj-database-url`?

Comment: R. Uziel, I did on my local install and everything is working.  I don't have a way to run that on DigitalOcean Apps until the application installs.

Comment: You could add dj-database-url to your `requirements.txt`, but I see you have set `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`, perhaps in your `.env`?  Are you using Heroku or digital ocean or both?  I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: R. Uziel, dj-database-url  is in the requirements.txt.  I didn't set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 I am not sure where I would set that on DigitalOcean apps.  I think DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 is set by default.

Comment: From my limited understanding, DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC is used specifically by Heroku.  Add your settings.py file.  Are you using Heroku or Digital Ocean or both?

Comment: Do not upload code screenshots, paste the console output of the full traceback in a markdown code block instead.

Also, question is unclear as it is written. Please rewrite it so its clear that the collectstatic admin command is causing troubles when deployed remotely but not locally.

Also, digital ocean apps probably has nothing to do with your issue. Please try to locally simulate your production configuration to provide a minimalistic reproduction example. You might run into the solution yourself in this process.